# Service is not getting hit

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am new to angularjs and am trying to get some information from a service call using Restangular, I am facing trouble while retrieving the data. Following is the code for the js file

```
angular.module('sol.user', ['restangular'])
        .controller('sol.user.UserController',UserController)
        .factory('sol.user.UserFactory',UserFactory);
        UserFactory.$inject =['$rootScope', 'Restangular'];
        UserController.$inject =['$rootScope', 'Restangular','sol.user.UserFactory'];

        function UserFactory($rootScope, Restangular) {
            alert("1");
              var UserController = {};
            var userDetails = Restangular.one('/user/userDetails');
            var a = userDetails.post();
            UserController = a;
            return UserController;
        }
        function UserController($rootScope, Restangular, user){
            $state.go('home.search');
            }




function RestConfig(RestangularProvider) {
      RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://10.98.3.2:9081/CustomerService/');

        RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: false,timeout: 20000});
        RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({brand: "wp",userBsb: "032000"});
        ;
        RestangularProvider.setFullRequestInterceptor(RequestInterceptor);
    }
```

I am not able to hit to the service url, while i am able to retrieve the data using RESTClient.
What seems to be the problem?
Also please tell me whats the difference between Restangular.all/one/